# Don't know how to escape complex regex characters

Tags: json, regex, jq

```
.+?sunday.+?"[0-9]:\d+.+
```

I am trying to implement this regex from a regex builder into a test function, but am unfamiliar with how to escape some of the characters for the syntax to work. I am using the regex in a `test(" ")` function

```
map({Row: .[] })
|   map(select(.Row.payload.hours | test(".+?sunday.+?"[0-9]:\d+.+")?))
```

Is the line of code giving me the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to encode the regex string as a JSON string. This is easy enough to do if you know something about JSON strings, but you could let jq do the walking, e.g. using

```
jq -R . regex.txt
```

assuming your regex is in the file regex.txt

Comment: hi, this is a bit advanced for me and i'm not too sure what you mean by this. typing in jq -R . to my console froze it :O

Comment: @user49 Your terminal probably didn't freeze. `jq` was waiting for you to type something. It's the same as typing just `cat` into the terminal. Hit [ctrl]+[d] to end your input.

Comment: got it. @peak, i currently use jq -s -f program.jq datadump.json to run my file. how do i incorporate the jq -R . regex.txt into this ? thank you again.

Comment: I had copy-and-paste in mind, but you could get fancy.

Comment: hi, im sorry, but i do not understand what you mean by this.

Comment: @peak, i'm so sorry for asking but could you explain this solution a bit and how to incorporate it in mine? i believe i have the correct REGEX for what i am trying to achieve.